# How to insert a google anylitics tag inside of a gatsby js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, gatsby

Trying figuring out how to place google-analytics tag in side of js file of Gatsby.

There's a [gatsby-plugin-analytics plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-analytics/?=analytics) , but an example shown there didn't give an idea to place the google analytics tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and maintainable way is using plugins. [`gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/) should work for you:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
        // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        gtagConfig: {
          optimize_id: "OPT_CONTAINER_ID",
          anonymize_ip: true,
          cookie_expires: 0,
        },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: false,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional
          respectDNT: true,
          // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
          exclude: ["/preview/**", "/do-not-track/me/too/"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

*Note: you can omit/remove the optional parameters, you only need to replace the `GA-TRACKING_ID` for your identifier.*

They have recently changed some API parameters that make your plugin (and some others) useless. The one provided is recommended by Gatsby in some tutorial parts.

Alternatively, depending on your Gatsby and plugins versions, the following plugin may also work for you:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Looks like I don't see any data in google analytics. Also, in my case, I don't have a TrackingID, bit MeasurementID. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: The tracking ID is the `G-number` that you've omitted in your question.